# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: @fortawesome/fontawesome-free , Capybara ,Rails 6.0.3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, font-awesome

my project work perfectly every font awesome icon load up successfully, but when I run tests using capybara it throws an error telling me it failed to import font-awsome.

```
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # SassC::SyntaxError:
     #   Error: File to import not found or unreadable: @fortawesome/fontawesome-free.
     #           on line 1493:2 of stdin
     #   >>  @import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free'; 
     #   
     #      -^
     #   stdin:1493

Finished in 3.94 seconds (files took 0.89442 seconds to load)
45 examples, 1 failure
```

my application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js";
```

my user feature test

```
   require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'registrations_controller', type: :system do
  before :each do
    User.create(name: 'test_name', email: 'test@test.com',
                password: '123456', password_confirmation: '123456',
                service: 'customer')
  end
  describe 'signup/in user' do
    it 'sign up' do
      visit new_user_registration_path
      fill_in('user_name', with: 'user1')
      fill_in('user_email', with: 'user1@user.com')
      fill_in('user_password', with: 'user12')
      fill_in('user_password_confirmation', with: 'user12')
      fill_in('user_service', with: 'customer')
      click_button('Sign up')
      expect(page).to have_content 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue was in CSS not in javascript,
on application.css I was importing font-awesome, and that causes an issue, I removed the line of code and now everything works perfectly.